# Причины закрытия БитКода

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange

Почему закрылся БитКод? Из-за обилия [подобных](http://user.hashcode.ru/questions/6729/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0) низкокачественных вопросов и «ответов» и/или по другим причинам?

Comment: Вся Сеть Знаний по сути "закрылась", потому что основатель ушёл в Stack Overflow, а всё ценное было импортировано в сеть Stack Exchange. Что касается БитКода и РутКода, то "[всё сложно](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2757)".